# What is the Conditional Formatting formula for two conditions?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, formatting, conditional-statements

I have an excel file that I need to format a certain color.

I have tried:

```
=AND(A:A=FALSE,B:B<>Null)
=AND(A:A="FALSE",B:B<>" ")
=AND(A:A=FALSE,NOT(ISBLANK(B:B)))
```

Along with multiple If-statements with this scenario.

Picture won't work but my file is somewhat like this:

```
     A    |   B
1 FALSE   |  1/14/2017
2 FALSE   |  4/21/2019
3 TRUE    |  3/9/2018
4 TRUE    |  2/24/2018
5 FALSE   | 
6 TRUE    |  9/21/2017 
7 FALSE   |   
8 FALSE   |  5/22/2019
```

I want to get the cells in "B" RED, if Column "A" is FALSE and Column "B" is not empty.

So Cells (B1, B2, AND B8) should be formatted to that color.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please select column B and apply a CF formula rule of:

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(B1)),A1=FALSE)
```

with red fill.

If you prefer shorter:

```
=(B1<>"")*NOT(A1)
```

Comment: So am I not allowed to select whole columns? If I use the first example, I would turn the whole column B to red since =AND(NOT(ISBLANK(B1)),A1=FALSE)  would be TRUE. Can I copy the formula over the other cells?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with that works:

```
=AND($A1=FALSE,$B1<>"")
```

the `""` is just two double quotes together, nothing in between.